# Pandas: How to summarize pandas cross table / frequency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'd like to summarize the results of a cross table/Frequency Matrix which looks at frequency of users having the same session, results is 4044 rows × 4044 columns

```
UserID  10  50  30  2488  9416 23197            ... 
UserID                                                                                  
10      4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
50      0   48  2   9   4   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
30      0   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2488    0   9   2   32  4   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9416    0   4   2   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Is there a way to summarize it to have user-to-user number of matches, something like:

```
UserID  UserID Occurance
10       50      2
30       2488    5
23197    10      3
30       50      1
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your Expected output.

Comment: Why would your starting table have a different number of rows than columns?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler good catch. It was a typo it's in fact a 4044 x 4044 square.

Comment: @Saad, thanks for confirming - I thought I was losing my mind there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Create a boolean mask that selects the upper triangular, non-diagonal values from the starting matrix
2. Reshape both this mask (with `.reshape()`) and the original matrix (with `.stack()`) into column vectors of equal size
3. Use boolean indexing to pick out the rows that you need.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(5, 5)), 
                  index=[10, 50, 30, 2488, 9416], 
                  columns=[10, 50, 30, 2488, 9416])

# Quick and dirty method to make the example data symmetric
df = df + df.T

df
      10    50    30    2488  9416
10       2     4     0     0     5
50       4     6     2     5     1
30       0     2     0     4     3
2488     0     5     4     4     0
9416     5     1     3     0     6

# To select the upper-triangular, non-diagonal entries,
# take a *lower*-triangular mask, np.tril, 
# and negate it with ~.
mask = (~np.tril(np.ones(df.shape)).astype('bool'))
mask
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])

# Prepare to select rows from the stacked df
mask = mask.reshape(df.size)

# Stack the columns of the starting matrix into a MultiIndex, 
# which results in a MultiIndexed Series;
# select the upper-triangular off-diagonal rows;
# reset the MultiIndex levels into columns
df.stack()[mask].reset_index().rename({'level_0': 'UserID_row', 
                                       'level_1': 'UserID_col', 
                                       0: 'Occurrence'}, axis=1)
   UserID_row  UserID_col  Occurrence
0          10          50           4
1          10          30           0
2          10        2488           0
3          10        9416           5
4          50          30           2
5          50        2488           5
6          50        9416           1
7          30        2488           4
8          30        9416           3
9        2488        9416           0
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeimbigler , when I apply the last line of code ( `df.stack()[mask].reset_index()` ),  I get the following error: ValueError: cannot insert UserID, already exists.  Some posts suggested using `reset_index(drop =True)` but it eliminates UserID as an index, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, before running anything, first rename either the index or the column of your starting DataFrame. Either `df.index.name = 'UserID_row'` or `df.columns.name = 'UserID_col'`.